# Is there a way to tell eclipse to save ALL open editors when running or debugging?

Tags: eclipse

Or even just saving the one editor that I have open?

Currently I'm editing a html file and I can hit the hotkey to get eclipse to run the file though the server instance. But I keep forgetting to save first.

I tried checking 'Preferences>General>Workspace>Save Automatically before build' but it's not actually building and it won't save what's in the editor.

I also tried setting 'Preferences>Run/Debug>Launching>Save required dirty editors before launching' to 'Always' but it still doesn't save the html page

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching.

with setting "Save required dirty editors before launching". Set it to "Always".

Comment: nope, i have that one set to "always" but i guess it's not a 'required' editor?